# Showing an infinite series of functions is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{c_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, $|c_n| \leq \frac{K}{n^3}$ for some $K>0$. Then $f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n \sin (nt)$ is differentiable, with $f'(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n c_n \cos (nt)$.

I tried taking limits, as follows:

Obviously, for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$f_n ' (t) =\frac{d}{dt} c_n \sin(nt)=nc_n\cos(nt)$$

and we have that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left| f_n' (nt) \right|\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n*\frac{K}{n^3}= K\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ giving us convergence of the series of partial sums $\sum_{n=1}^k f_n'(t)$ to $f'(t)$ for all $t$, in fact uniform convergence by the Weirstrauss M-Test.

Is this answer correct? Is it complete? I am shaky with it, but I can't find what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer isn't complete. In fact you should prove the simple convergence of the given series $\sum_n f_n$ and the uniform convergence of $\sum_n f'_n$.

Comment: Thanks. I would say $\sum_n |f_n| \leq \sum_n \frac{K}{n^3} $ so we have convergence for $f(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. The uniform convergence of $\sum_n f_n'$ is because of the M-Test, since $|f_n'|\leq \frac{K}{n^2}$ and $\sum_n \frac{K}{n^2}$ converges. So $f'$ exists for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$ and is equal to $\sum_n f_n'$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes now it's a complete answer:-)